# Load image from URL using Picasso in CustomListView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an issue where I want to load an image as a background within a custom listview. I have tried everything I can think of but as its an ImageView on a different xml file it wont work. When I move the image view to the other xml file it works as it's defined at the start.

Here is the code:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://jaunt-ddc86.appspot.com/");

        storageRef.child("SYMmA73ONtSkOcYWT7PrDQ1892s1").child("mapbg.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(BackgroundMain);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });
```

The xml file the ImageView is on is called feed_listview.xml

Answer (score 1):

So you wanna load images into a view, why don't you skip it to,

```
ImageView yes = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IdInImageViewInXML); 

Picasso.with(this).load("YourImageURL").into(yes);
```

And Firebase Storage up there is not needed.